# Matlab @fminunc objective function optimization

Tags: matlab, function, optimization, maximize

I am currently practicing a simple function optimization in Matlab and hope you could provide with little assistance / explanation on the following error:

```
%quadramin.m
function z=quadramin(param,data);
z=data.*(param(1).^2 - param(2).^3)+3;

%quadramin_lik.m
function quadlik = quadramin_lik(param,data);
%pseudo/ad-hoc log-likelihood function
quadlik = quadramin(param,data)- 10;

%script.m
data=trnd(5,6,1);
param0=[2,3];
[param_eq,exitflag,output,grad,hessian] = ... 
fminunc(@(param) quadramin_lik(param,data),param0)
```

Output after executing %script.m: **Error using fminunc (line 333)
User supplied objective function must return a scalar value.**

ps: It looks paradoxical as the user-defined functions quadramin && quadramin_lik do return values.

Thanks

Comment: Both your functions return a vector of values whereas `fminunc` requires that the function returns a **scalar / single** value.  The error is pretty clear.  The function `fminunc` is trying to find the best solution that minimizes a cost function, so what you need to supply is a cost function.  Therefore, perhaps try summing the results in each function before returning them.... but doing that doesn't guarantee a global minimum because `fminunc` assumes that your cost function is convex.

Comment: summing the pseudo log-likehood function to return a scalar/single value works indeed. Thanks for the comments. Finally if i'd like to use @fmincon, am I correct to set `lb=[0,2], ub=[0,+inf] ` if `0<=x(1)<=2` and `x(2)` belongs to R+? in a nutshell `param_eq = fmincon(@(param) quadramin_lik(param,data),param0,[],[],[],[],[0,2],[0, inf])`? Cheers

Comment: I have no idea how your linear program is set up so I can't comment on what you have coded is correct.

Comment: It should not , a priori, matter too much, but I am very grateful to the main scalar issue raised and solved, as i could not guess the cause of this error. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your functions return a vector of values whereas `fminunc` requires that the function returns a **scalar / single** value. The error is pretty clear. The function `fminunc` is trying to find the best solution that minimizes a cost function, so what you need to supply is a cost function.

Therefore, perhaps try summing the results in each function before returning them.... but doing that doesn't guarantee a global minimum because fminunc assumes that your cost function is convex.  However, judging from your comments as you are computing log likelihoods, then summing is what you should be doing any way!